# plt.eventplot refuses lineoffsets

Tags: python, matplotlib

This should be quite easy to reproduce:

```
plt.eventplot(positions=[1, 2, 3], lineoffsets=[1, 2, 3])
```

raises

```
ValueError: lineoffsets and positions are unequal sized sequences
```

For reasons I can't figure out, because they clearly aren't.

Comment: Are you using matplotliv 2.0 or above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to plot 3 lines, at different starting heights (offsets). The way this works with [`plt.eventplot`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.eventplot.html) is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

positions = np.array([1, 2, 3])[:,np.newaxis]   # or np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
offsets = [1,2,3]

plt.eventplot(positions, lineoffsets=offsets)
plt.show()
```

You have to set the offset for each group of data you want to plot. In your case, you have to divide the list into a 3D array (shape `(m,n)` with `m` the number of datasets, and `n` number of data points per set). This way `plt.eventplot` knows it has to use the different offsets for each group of data. Also see [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/eventplot_demo.html) example.

Comment: Just to mention: reshaping the list to a transposed array could be done like `positions=np.array([1, 2, 3])[:,np.newaxis]` (which would not require to know the size in advance).